# Making a grid with jquery - code not complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, raphael

I'm trying to figure out how to make my code work and look like this:

[image: GOAL]

The question is:

> Create an HTML page with a text input, a button, and container for a Raphaël paper object. We will have the user enter a number in the form and click the button, and then draw an n×n grid of squares.
>   If the user enters 8 in the text input and clicks the button, you should draw eight rows and columns of little squares. To do this, you will need two for loops nested inside each other like this:*

```
for ( row=1; ... ) {
  for ( col=1; ... ) {
    ...
  }
}
```

> In the (inner-most) loop body, draw a little square on the paper with an x and y value calculated from the loop counters so the squares end up in a grid pattern.

This is my code:

```js
x = 0
y = 0
grid = function() {
 entered_text = $('#howmany').val();
 for (row = entered_text; row <= 15; row += 1){
    for (col = entered_text; col <= 15; col += 1) {
   r = paper.rect(x, y, 20, 20);
   x = r * col
  } 
  y = r + row;
 }
}


setup = function() {
  paper = Raphael('svg', 400, 400)
  jQuery('#start').click(grid)
 
}

jQuery(document).ready(setup)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<script src="http://cmpt165.csil.sfu.ca/js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://cmpt165.csil.sfu.ca/js/raphael-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="logic.js"></script>
<title>Exercise 11</title>
</head> 
<body>
<h1>Exercise 11</h1>


<div class="gridsize">Grid Size:
<input type="text" id="howmany" />
<button id="start">Go</button></div>

<div id="svg"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any error messages? What happens when you run your code? BTW. you should use let, var or const to define your variables, the way you declare them in your code, they are all global properties of the window object, which is very bad practice.

Comment: *"I don't know if my .js is correct so far to make the grid appear"* - You *do* know that it is *not* correct, because it doesn't work. Note that when you coded `for (row = entered_text; row <= 15; row += 1)` that in itself was already different to the sample code from the instructions.

Comment: @nnnnnn I made it `for (row = 1; row <= entered_text; row += 1) ` and it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, you were just multiplying the `r` value, a non number, by `col`, which will return `NaN`, which isn't good.  Then I also converted `entered_text` to a number and modified the `for` loop.  So I went ahead and updated it.  If you want padding, simply increase all `20` to `25`.

```js
x = 0
y = 0
grid = function() {
 entered_text = Number($('#howmany').val());
 for (row = 0; row < entered_text; row += 1){
    for (col = 0; col < entered_text; col += 1) {
   paper.rect(20 * col, 20 * row, 20, 20);
  } 
 }
}


setup = function() {
  paper = Raphael('svg', 400, 400)
  jQuery('#start').click(grid)
 
}

jQuery(document).ready(setup)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<script src="http://cmpt165.csil.sfu.ca/js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://cmpt165.csil.sfu.ca/js/raphael-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="logic.js"></script>
<title>Exercise 11</title>
</head> 
<body>
<h1>Exercise 11</h1>


<div class="gridsize">Grid Size:
<input type="text" id="howmany" />
<button id="start">Go</button></div>

<div id="svg"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Should be `<` rather than `<=` in the loop conditions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! :D

Comment: Hey, if you could mark as solution, it'd help a lot.  And no problem.  nnnnnn is correct though, I updated my answer.